# URLs are inconsistently being redirected using ISAPI urlrewrite 3.0

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, asp-classic, isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to create some friendly urls.

- search/real
- searc/tpp

everything is working fine except the browser changes to reflect the unfriendly url.  Even though I am not specifying a redirect.  Please see the last two lines of my .htaccess file below. It seems intermittent too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sc-pa.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]

RewriteMap  lc int:tolower

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*web_content/pdf/.*
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf) /web_content/pdf/$1 [R=301]


RewriteRule pasite-(.*\.asp)$  /content/$1 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule home\.asp$  / [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^.*search/real/?$ /content/search_real_property.asp <--my problem child 1
RewriteRule ^.*search/tpp/?$ /content/search_tangible.asp <--problem child 2
```

# Rewrite script

```
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /content/search_real_property.asp
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/content/search_real_property.asp' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'content/search_real_property.asp'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/css/site.css
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/css/site.css' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/css/site.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/css/csshorizontalmenu.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /Include/js/JavaFunctions.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/Include/js/JavaFunctions.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/Include/js/JavaFunctions.js' pattern='.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'Include/js/JavaFunctions.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692832/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery-1.4.4.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/HoverDropDwn.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/HoverDropDwn.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/HoverDropDwn.js' pattern='.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/HoverDropDwn.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js' pattern='.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/css/print.css
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691200/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/css/print.css' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/css/print.css'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/jquery.cookie.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jquery.cookie.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.cookie.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/header.jpg
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/images/header.jpg' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17692424/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'images/header.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/HoverImg.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/HoverImg.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/HoverImg.js' pattern='.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/HoverImg.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17689976/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js' pattern='[A-Z]' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '(?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf)' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'pasite-(.*\.asp)$' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern 'home\.asp$' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/real/?$' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17693240/initial] (3) applying pattern '^.*search/tpp/?$' to uri 'include/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/AllHazardsButton.jpg
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (1) Htaccess process request c:\proj\www\.htaccess
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/AllHazardsButton.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net)' => not-matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'images/AllHazardsButton.jpg'
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/images/AllHazardsButton.jpg' pattern='[A-Z]' => matched
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/SheltersButton.jpg
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17690792/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
::1 ::1  Fri, 23-Sep-2011  11:25:04 GMT [localhost/sid#1][rid#17691608/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/images/AllHazardsButton.jpg' pattern='.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)' => not-matched
```

Comment: If you use any HTTP Debugger (like Firebug's 'Net' panel or similar) do you see any redirects occurring? In any case -- try adding the `[L]` flag at the end of those rules. Also, check your code for those pages -- redirect may occur there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If redirect occurs in ISAPI_Rewrite, you can see it in rewrite.log (you can show a part of it here and I'll tell you if redirect is there).
And as LazyOne already said make sure redirect does not occur on your asp page.

Comment: Try the following pair of rules for your problem child 1: RewriteRule ^content/search_real_property\.asp$ /search/real/$ [NC,R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^search/real/?$ /content/search_real_property.asp [NC,L]